# Git - folder structure problems

Tags: git, github, directory, git-clone

I'm having trouble with a Git Repository that I was added to due to its folder structure.

The Git repo folder structure is:

```
.
├── .git
└── /dev
    └── /src
        └── --all the code files
```

This project is a website, and on the machine that we are hosting the website the `src/` folder needs to be the top-level folder and named `htdocs/`.

Is there any chance that I can Git Clone the repo without the `dev/` folder and still be able to pull changes with Git?

I've tried `git clone https://github.com/foobar/foo.git htdocs` but that just renames the `dev/` folder to htdocs.

And our hosting situation does not allow me to make symbolic links, so I can't go that way.

Is there any way that I can clone the Git repo, or am I going to have to change the folder structure of the git repo to:

```
.
├── .git
└── /src (or /htdocs)
    └── --all the code files
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the git repo structure (`git mv dev/src .`) would be the easiest solution.

If `src/` doesn't fit at the root level in this repo, then a solution would be:

- [splitting the repo in two](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Split+a+repository+in+two#Splitarepositoryintwo-UsingGittosplit-outadirectory) (one for `src/`, one for the rest),
- referencing the `src` repo from the main repo as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and sorry for the super late reply).
I ended up just having to change the whole repo by moving all the files up two levels.